# Alternative to Excel INDIRECT that works on closed files, and links to workbook based on cell value?

Tags: vba, excel

I've seen many questions on this forum about linking Excel files based on cell values and INDIRECT always pops up as an answer, and it does do function and fill my sheet the way that I want, but I need to find a way to work with the source file being closed. My problem when it comes to linking, is that the file path to pull the data from will not be known until part of the file name is entered into a cell.

For example, in 'Print Summary' workbook, Sheet1 Cell A2 is where the file name is entered as a number 12345 (and gets auto-formatted to place 'WIP' in front) which represents WIP12345.xls. WIP12345.xls is a form that holds information that needs to populate certain columns across row 2. WIP12345.xls is an order form and completed days ahead. Once it has been approved, the summary workbook is updated with the WIP#.

I did CONCATENATE WIP12345 and .xls to create the file name WIP12345.xls on Sheet2, and I have a Macro that copies and pastes special as value to turn the result into text. But, I can't find a way to create a formula that will take this value and lookup the file to pull information from. I need to pull and fill information from  different cells to 10 columns down 43 rows (each row representing a different WIP#####.xls file).

I'm guessing VBA is the only way to go, but I have no idea how to write it. Anyone have a direction they can point me in? I hope I'm coming across clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The free add-in [morefunc.xll](http://download.cnet.com/Morefunc/3000-2077_4-10423159.html) contains a function called Indirect.Ext, which works with closed worbooks.

Comment: Ok, found this to complete the installation [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/467397-morefunc-release-excel-2010-a.html)